# Marginalization of latents in SEM

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

As I understand it, there are tricks to marginalize-out latent quantities in structural equation models, but I'm having trouble finding explanations of how this is achieved that aligns with both my minimal math background and typical use case. So I thought I'd post a couple examples here showing how I code things without marginalization and see if folks could show how marginalization would be achieved.

Generally I've come to like an approach to SEM identification whereby I model all latents as standard normals, weights as correlations, and positive constrain one weight coming from each latent.

First up is a model with three levels of latents:

[image: model1 dependency graph]

with Stan code:

```
data{
    int n_id ;
    int n_obs ;
    matrix[n_obs,n_id] a_obs ;
    matrix[n_obs,n_id] b_obs ;
    matrix[n_obs,n_id] c_obs ;
    matrix[n_obs,n_id] d_obs ;
}
parameters{
    // common latent
    vector[n_id] abcd ;

    // positive-constrained correlations
    real<lower=0,upper=1> r_abcd_ab ;
    real<lower=0,upper=1> r_ab_a ;
    real<lower=0,upper=1> r_cd_c ;

    // unconstrained correlations (using unit-vector reduces compute)
    unit_vector[2] r_abcd_cd ;
    unit_vector[2] r_ab_b ;
    unit_vector[2] r_cd_d ;

    // helpers (residuals on unit-scale)
    vector[n_id] ab_ ;
    vector[n_id] cd_ ;
    vector[n_id] a_ ;
    vector[n_id] b_ ;
    vector[n_id] c_ ;
    vector[n_id] d_ ;

    // across-id SDs of the observed variables
    real<lower=0> a_sd ;
    real<lower=0> b_sd ;
    real<lower=0> c_sd ;
    real<lower=0> d_sd ;

    // common across-observation measurement noise
    real<lower=0> noise ;

}
model{

    // priors
    abcd ~ std_normal() ;
    ab_ ~ std_normal() ;
    cd_ ~ std_normal() ;
    a_ ~ std_normal() ;
    b_ ~ std_normal() ;
    c_ ~ std_normal() ;
    d_ ~ std_normal() ;
    a_sd ~ weibull(2,1) ;
    b_sd ~ weibull(2,1) ;
    c_sd ~ weibull(2,1) ;
    d_sd ~ weibull(2,1) ;
    noise ~ weibull(2,1) ;

    // abcd to ab & cd
    vector[n_id] ab = (
        abcd * r_abcd_ab
        + ab_ * sqrt(1-square(r_abcd_ab)) // for contrained correlations, need to compute this explicitly
    ) ;
    vector[n_id] cd = (
        abcd * r_abcd_cd[1]
        + cd_ * r_abcd_cd[2] // for unconstrained correlations, computed automatically
    ) ;

    // ab to a & b
    vector[n_id] a = (
        (
            ab * r_ab_a
            + a_ * sqrt(1-square(r_ab_a))
        )
        * a_sd
    ) ;
    vector[n_id] b = (
        (
            ab * r_ab_b[1]
            + b_ * r_ab_b[2]
        )
        * b_sd
    ) ;

    // cd to c & d
    vector[n_id] c = (
        (
            cd * r_cd_c
            + c_ * sqrt(1-square(r_cd_c))
        )
        * c_sd
    ) ;
    vector[n_id] d = (
        (
            cd * r_cd_d[1]
            + d_ * r_cd_d[2]
        )
        * d_sd
    ) ;

    // likelihood
    for(i in 1:n_id){
        a_obs[,n_id] ~ normal(a[n_id],noise) ;
        b_obs[,n_id] ~ normal(b[n_id],noise) ;
        c_obs[,n_id] ~ normal(c[n_id],noise) ;
        d_obs[,n_id] ~ normal(d[n_id],noise) ;
    }

}
```

And the second has similar latent structure as the first, with the twist that multiple latents are connected to a given observed variable in a simple well-identified manner:

[image]

Stan code:

```
data{
    ... // same as first model
    matrix[n_obs,n_id] a_minus_b_obs ;
    matrix[n_obs,n_id] a_plus_b_obs ;
    matrix[n_obs,n_id] c_minus_d_obs ;
    matrix[n_obs,n_id] c_plus_d_obs ;
}
... // same as first model
model{
    ... // same as first model
    // likelihood
    for(i in 1:n_id){
        a_minus_b_obs[,n_id] ~ normal(a[n_id]-b[n_id],noise) ;
        a_plus_b_obs[,n_id] ~ normal(a[n_id]+b[n_id],noise) ;
        c_minus_d_obs[,n_id] ~ normal(c[n_id]-d[n_id],noise) ;
        c_plus_d_obs[,n_id] ~ normal(c[n_id]+[n_id],noise) ;
    }

}
```

I feel like if I could see how a marginalized version of each of these is achieved, that would give me the much better leverage to understand marginalization in SEM. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to approach this marginalization through matrix representations, and below is based on the LISREL approach. I am not sure that I am matching your model code exactly, but it should be close enough to be useful.

You start by building a matrix of regressions between different latent variables. Below, the "from" variables are in columns and the "to" variables are in rows. Call this matrix B.
\begin{matrix}
& abcd & ab & cd & a & b & c & d \\
abcd & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
ab & r1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
cd & r2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
a & 0 & r3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
b & 0 & r4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
c & 0 & 0 & r5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
d & 0 & 0 & r6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
where $r1$ to $r6$ are those correlation parameters in your code.

Your latent variable variances then go in a diagonal matrix of the same size, call it $\Psi$.
\begin{matrix}
& abcd & ab & cd & a & b & c & d \\
abcd & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
ab & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
cd & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
a & 0 & 0 & 0 & sd_a^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & sd_b^2 & 0 & 0 \\
c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & sd_c^2 & 0 \\
d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & sd_d^2 \\
\end{matrix}

Then the joint distribution of all the latent variables is
Normal$(0, (I - B)^{-1} \Psi (I - B^\prime)^{-1})$.

Now you just need to connect this to the observed variables. For your first model, define a matrix from latents to observeds as $\Lambda$:
\begin{matrix}
& abcd & ab & cd & a & b & c & d \\
a_{obs} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
b_{obs} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
c_{obs} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
d_{obs} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}

Now your joint distribution of $(a_{obs}, b_{obs}, c_{obs}, d_{obs})$ is Normal with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Lambda (I - B)^{-1} \Psi (I - B^\prime)^{-1}) \Lambda^\prime + \Theta$, where $\Theta$ is a $4\times 4$ diagonal matrix with noise$^2$ as the diagonal entries. For your second model, I believe you just need to modify the $\Lambda$ matrix to have two 1s in each row (some of which are negative).

There are probably simpler expressions for these specific models, but the utility of this approach is that it works for many different models.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I'll give a shot to expressing this in Stan and report back...